# attempting to get the number of friends from facebook api - android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to the number of friends from facebook authentication api in an android application needed to call facebook permission api. Below is a snippet I am using

```
fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends"));
```

the app fails with a json exception at this line

```
PUBLICPROFILE = object.getString("public_profile"); //error here
```

**EDITTED - Here is a snippet of my attempt:**

```
Name = object.getString("name");
                                    Email = object.getString("email");
                                    DOB = object.getString("birthday");
                                    DOB = object.getString("birthday");
                                    PUBLICPROFILE = object.getString("/me/friends");
                                    Log.v("Email = ", " " + Email);
                                    Log.v("PUBLIC PROFILE = ", " " + PUBLICPROFILE);
```

Please does anyone know how I can the number of friends from facebook on android login authentication

Comment: what error exactly? you get the number of friends with the /me/friends endpoint

Comment: @luschn org.json.JSONException: No value for /me/friends

Comment: i am not sure what you are trying there, and i am not experienced with android, but it seems wrong to use "getString" with an api endpoint (/me/friends), or with a permission (public_profile)...also, there is a duplicate line for the birthday field...

Comment: this is my problem, I dont know the exact parameter to get the number of friends >>> PUBLICPROFILE = object.getString("/me/friends");

Comment: the error occurs at that line.....

Comment: "object" is an object (obviously), and you get a specific string/field of that object with "getString", right? so why are you trying to get "/me/friends", which is an API ENDPOINT, aka the api call you actually have to make in order to get the friends (and the count). make sure you know what each line in your source actually does, this is just wrong and you need to understand why.

Answer (score 1):

As per the `facebook developer` api  `/{user-id}/friends`

1.the User's friends who have installed the app

2.the User's total number of friends (including those who have not installed the app making the query)

After getting facebook token you can use this implementation

```
     GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
      accessToken,
      "/{user-id}/friends",
      new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
          // Insert your code here
        }
    });

    request.executeAsync();
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/

Comment: I am doing something different from your approach

Comment: right now, according to the source in your question, you are not using the /me/friends endpoint, which is exactly what you have to do. the answer is correct and pretty much what you need (you can just replace "{user-id}" with "me").

Comment: if you use the /me/friends endpoint as suggested in the answer, you will get a list of all friends who authorized your app AND a "summary" field with the total count of friends.

Comment: {Response:  responseCode: 404, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {user-id}}}

Comment: On attempting this answer