# How to get facebook friends list in android?

Tags: android, facebook

```
Code:


 AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                "/"+fbUserid+"/friendlists",
                                null,
                                HttpMethod.GET,
                                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponseresponse) {
 Log.e("friendsRes",response.toString());        
                                    }}).executeAsync();
```

> {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[]}, error: null}

In this code i am not able to get friends list in android, there is have any other code filter of `facebook` friends. Thanks!!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47943716/3505534

Comment: "/"+fbUserid+"/friends",
        {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":161}}, error: null} i got response is

Answer (score -1):

```
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{friend-list-id}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

**Note:** A user access token with `read_custom_friendlists` permission is required.

Comment: {friend-list-id}" how to get this id

Comment: make sure you understand the difference between "friends" and "friendlists". this will not return your friends either.